# What's the point of using this onLoad function from "JavaScript: The Definite Guide"?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onload

The code snippet below is from the book *JavaScript: The Definite Guide*.

I have some questions about it. From my point of view, I don't anticipate any scenario where there is a must to use the `onLoad` function.

I think that this chunk of code has to be used as global javascript instead of as part of an event handler. If it is invoked in an event handler of a button, the load event on window must have already been triggered. As a result, the registered function will never be invoked.

However, if it is used as the global javascript, `onLoad.loaded` is always false when the `onLoad` function is invoked.

Why not just register the load event on window, instead of checking whether `onLoad.loaded` is true or false?

```js
// Register the function f to run when the document finishes loading.
// If the document has already loaded, run it asynchronously ASAP.
function onLoad(f) {
    if (onLoad.loaded) // If document is already loaded
        window.setTimeout(f, 0); // Queue f to be run as soon as possible
    else if (window.addEventListener) // Standard event registration method
        window.addEventListener("load", f, false);
    else if (window.attachEvent) // IE8 and earlier use this instead
        window.attachEvent("onload", f);
}

// Start by setting a flag that indicates that the document is not loaded yet.
onLoad.loaded = false;

// And register a function to set the flag when the document does load.
onLoad(function() {
    onLoad.loaded = true;
});
```

Comment: "*onLoad.loaded is always false*" - why do you think so? It's explicitly set to `true` in the snippet.

Comment: When you have lots of scripts that your application depends on them you want to make sure that they are loaded before you start running you application.

Comment: This may be useful for plugins, if you don't know where or how the user is going to include the plugin. If the user includes the plugin dynamically after the page has loaded, then assigning a `Document.onLoad` event handler will do nothing, as the page is already loaded. So basically this just adds an abstraction layer to allow a plugin to function correctly no matter where it is loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the usage scenario.

You are right, the above snippet should be executed on startup, before the webpage completes loading, so that `onLoad.loaded` is accurately assigned.

However, the `onLoad` function that is defined by the script can be invoked from anywhere, later, even from button event handlers etc.

Comment: If the onLoad function is later invoked from button event handlers, the onLoad.loaded must have been set to true because of the load event. Then, it is always the branch  window.setTimeout(f, 0) that gets executed. If this is the case, there is no need to use the onLoad function-------just use window.setTimeout(f, 0)，or just f().

Comment: @ZhengquanBai: yes, that's the purpose of that flag. But there are also events where you don't know whether `load` had already been triggered (e.g. when loading scripts asynchronously, or when writing functions that might both be called during startup or from button clicks)